# Map Component deprecated in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I'm facing some challenge in using maps, my map component is deprecated, is there something I should do to be able to use it and also would like to know the steps required to intergrate map keys to Codename One?

Answer (score 3):

`MapComponent` is marked deprecated to discourage its use, but it should still work fine.  The reason we discourage its use is because the [Google Maps lib](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps) is better than it in almost every way.  You should look at using that instead if possible.

There are instructions in the [readme file](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps) on how to integrate your keys.

Answer (score 1):

The Google maps library is updated with improvments please go throgh the below link. 
[new update n google map](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-improved-native-google-maps.html)

you have added it from build hints as shown in as attached image.
[image]

Comment: thanks, But where do I add this line: javascript.googlemaps.key=YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_API_KEY
android.xapplication=<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY"/>
ios.afterFinishLaunching=[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_IOS_API_KEY"];? Do I add it on my Statemachine?

Comment: you have added it from build hints as shown in as attached image as shown in above image.

Comment: Wow thanks... all the permission are already done for me.. Codename One made this one to be very simple, one last question, where do I add my API_KEYS.. for android, ios and javascript?

Comment: javascript.googlemaps.key=YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_API_KEY
android.xapplication=<meta-data 
you can add those from the build hints as the following parameters and values

android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY"/>
ios.afterFinishLaunching=[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_IOS_API_KEY"];